# How to redirect all traffic from nginx to nodeJS with proxy-pass

Tags: node.js, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

When I setup simple nginx location to catch all traffic to root and proxy-pass to nodeJS on port 3000, when I request http://example.com/something

When I enter mydomain.net I got result from nodeJS, but when I tried example.com/something, I'm getting 502 Bad Gateway.

```
server {
        listen xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80;
        server_name example.com  www.example.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000/;
        }

}
```

I expect nodeJS to handle rest of url (after /) as this working without nginx, when nodeJS is alone on port 80.

Answer (score 0):

aste the following code in the file and make sure to change example.com to your domain (or IP), and 1337 to your Node.js application port:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name example.com;

location / {
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass         "http://127.0.0.1:3000";
}
}
```

than

```
sudo nginx -t 
sudo service nginx restart
```

Comment: Thanks on anwser, but still getting Bad Gateway on non root urls, like: www.example.com/test

Comment: Agreed, this does not work with any actually fully-made applications that need to load CSS and images on the side.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out that nginx code was ok, my SSL configuration seems to make problem here and after checked error log of nginx, started again and get successfully all locations to NodeJS. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name www.frostoven.com;
  root /var/www/frostoven.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass            http://127.0.0.1:3000$request_uri;
    proxy_http_version    1.1;
    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header      Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header      Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header      Host $http_host;
    proxy_cache_bypass    $http_upgrade;
   }
}
```

For SSL, you can add something like this below the `listen 80` section:

```
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 ssl;
  include snippets/your-cert-info.conf;
  include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
```

The above will not only work for root, but for any URI such as `example.com/whatever?test`.